# Spring REST Api + Spring Security

Tags: java, spring-mvc, spring-security, rest, swagger

Пишем Spring REST Api и дали ТЗ припилить секюрити, но возник вопрос, как указать авторизацию юзера если мы не используем jsp для авторизацию, а пользуемся swagger'ом. Как в рест запросах указать `action="j_spring_security_check"`, чтобы можно было залогинить юзера?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Почитай про протокол oAuth2.
Он хорошо ложится на клиент-серверную архитектуру. Так же легко можно добавить логин через соц. сети.

Вот ссылка с примерами:

https://spring.io/guides/tutorials/spring-boot-oauth2/

Comment: уже давно решили этот вопрос, но этот так же подходит. можно еще сделать через JWT.